# openpyxl: TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'guess_types'

Tags: python, openpyxl

when i'm try to use

`load_workbook(filename=self.file_name, guess_types=True)`

When i'm appending new data to existing sheet all the cells are formatted as 'General'

I want to use the .append() method and to keep the originals cells types from the loaded workbook

I'm getting this Error:

```
in __init__
    self.wb = load_workbook(filename=self.file_name,guess_types=True)
TypeError: load_workbook() got an unexpected keyword argument 'guess_types'
```

(python 3.7)
Openpyxl last ver

Comment: you might want to give an example of the file you are trying to read and how you are importing openpyxl.  This issue is not reproducible as this function works fine without the error

Comment: Support for `guess_types` has been dropped.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show your `openpyxl` version.

Comment: @CharlieClark: guess_types is still referenced in docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html